# Search a specific column in pandas from a terminal input and print its values

Tags: python, pandas

I want to search in a pandas datasheet a specific column given from terminal input and print its values.
Here the code i've tried

```
    maps= pnd.read_excel('Maps.xlsx',  index_col=0, index_row=0, header=1)
    M = input ('which maps are you playing?')

    if M in maps.columns:
      print ('ok')

    w = maps.M.values
```

the problem is python does not read M as a variable but instead as 'M'. I've already tried something like `w=maps.str(M).values` or similar but nothing.
Any suggestion? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you do:

```
w = maps[M].values
```